# Gemfile group is used for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know the "group" method is used for specify gems for specific environments.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0.beta.19"
  gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 0.3.2"
  gem "webrat", ">= 0.7.2.beta.1"
end
```

But I dont get what it means. So these could just be used when im in development and test environment?

But will it be installed in production?

Comment: Better answered here: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/09/the-how-and-why-of-bundler-groups/ by way of duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645968/groups-in-a-gemfile-in-rails-3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means you don't need this gem in production. But if you want use test or development mode, you need it.

You can install without some group with bundler like :

```
bundle install --without= development test
```

In this case all gems in development and test group are not installed and not required.

Answer (score 0):

// A group can be include or extract whenever we require while installing the bundle of gems

Suppose we have following group for staging and production, we don't want them to be included while installing gems

```
group :staging, :production do
  gem 'libv8'
  gem 'piwik_analytics', '~> 1.0.1'
end
```

So, install without the group of staging or production

`bundle install --without staging proudction`