# Groups in a Gemfile in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

In my Gemfile in Rails I have these groups:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "spork"
  gem "launchy"
end

group :bdd do
  gem "cucumber-rails"
  gem "rspec-rails"
end
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/09/the-how-and-why-of-bundler-groups/:

> Specifying groups allows you to do two things. First, you can install
>   the gems in your Gemfile, minus specific groups. For instance, Rails
>   puts mysql and pg in a database group so that if you’re just working
>   on ActionPack, you can bundle install --without db and run the
>   ActionPack tests without having to worry about getting the gems
>   installed.
>
> Second, you can list specific groups to autorequire using
>   Bundler.require. By default, Bundler.require requires all the gems in
>   the default group (which is all the gems that have no explicit group).
>   You can also say Bundler.require(:default, :another_group) to require
>   specific groups.

Answer (score 11):

*Grouping your dependencies allows you to perform operations on the entire group.* See: http://gembundler.com/v1.3/groups.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer updated to Bundler 1.3 -> http://gembundler.com/v1.3/groups.html